# dask delayed outputting delayed results despite using compute

Tags: python, dask

I wrote this simple function to get the % of nan values (it works easily with Pandas, but I want dask)

```
@delayed(pure=True)
def nanas():
   return ((df.isna().sum()/df.shape[0])*100)
```

and then call it through

```
nanas().compute()
```

I have tried putting the delayed and the compute in different places but I get things like:

```
Delayed('mul-702603f442eca568be1e3870be16b005')
```

one like that for each column, as if I still had to compute something

Comment: can you share a reproducible example?